# Access an array of objects

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, object, casting

I have the following object

```
Object myobj = new[]
{

    new MyClass(),
    new MyClass()

};
```

How can I access it as array ?

I've tried `((Array) myobj)[0]` but gives me error:

> ((Array) myobj)[0] Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Array'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Initialization**

```
var myobj = new[]
{
    new MyClass(),
    new MyClass()
};
```

**Safety Usage**

```
var myClass = myobj.ElementAt(0) as MyClass;
//Or var myClass = myobj[0] as MyClass;

if (myClass != null)
{
    //Do the Stuff
}
```

Comment: actually I prefer using `MyClass myobj = new[] {};` because I need this variable as global. Thanks mate you helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

When you declare the type as `object`, then you can only access the members declared on the `Object` class. You should specify the type more precisely:

```
MyClass[] myobj = new[]
{
    new MyClass(),
    new MyClass()
};
```